# Animation Issue when Reusing code Android

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I have an application where i spawn a new enemy every 4 seconds. the enemy goes from right to left using an`TranslateAnimation`. This animation takes 7 seconds total.

The problem that I'm facing now is that when the animation is running, every time that i spawn a new enemy, the animation stops for the old one and starts animating the new enemy.

Is there any way to animate two different objects using the same TranslateAnimation?

Just in case, here is my animation

```
        translate= new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.ABSOLUTE, (float) 1.0,
            Animation.ABSOLUTE, (float) -4.0,
            Animation.ABSOLUTE,0,
            Animation.ABSOLUTE,0);

    translate.setDuration(10000);
    translate.setFillAfter(true);
    //newIV is the enemy's ImageView
    newIV.startAnimation(translate);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply animation like this

make an animation `xml` in `anim` folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
     <translate
        android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="500" 
        />
   </set>
```

Then code in class

```
final Animation RightToLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
                R.anim.right_to_left);


        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.yourImage))
                .startAnimation(RightToLeft);
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: I tried that before but i got the same problem. What I have to admit is that I haven't used the final. By the way, here you are creating the ImageView like this ((ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.yourImage)) it is the same as creating Imageview IV= ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yourImage)) ?

Comment: Yes it is same. I will edit my answer to clear the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a same animation to Different views in same position.try to use animationLisener

```
    translate.setAnimationListener(new TranslateAnimation.AnimationListener() {                             @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }
            @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) 
        {
         animation.setFillAfter(false);
         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params =(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)mLogo.getLayoutParams();
         //Set your firest view layout or hide the previous newIV
        //This ll avoid filckering
         animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
         animation.setDuration(1);
         ImageView mLogo = new ImageView(activity);// Second enemy as u said     

         animation = new TranslateAnimation(
        Animation.ABSOLUTE, (float) 1.0,
        Animation.ABSOLUTE, (float) -4.0,
        Animation.ABSOLUTE,0,
        Animation.ABSOLUTE,0);      
         mLogo.startAnimation(animation);mLogo.setLayoutParams(params);
         mLogo.clearAnimation();
         mLogo.startAnimation(animation);
            }
});
```

This ll animate When first enemy going to end create a new instance of animation and use.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but what i really intended to do is to run two enemies with a delay shorter than the animation time, so when the second enemy starts animating, the first one keeps running. Like having both enemies on screen at the same time but one behind another

Comment: Then you need to create a new TranslateAnimation instance